# Passing this object using JSON in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been struggling with keeping the session state of a tabular menu using cookies using aforementioned techniques. This has been an open bug, for far to long, and honestly my jquery skills are non-existent:

It is almost functionally perfect, though I'm sure a much nicer rewrite is possible
This single line is the problem in the following

```
**$(activate).parent().addClass('active');**
```

This is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var cookie = $.cookie('menu_cookie');
            if (cookie === null) {
                //create cookie
                $.cookie('menu_cookie', '#tab-1!88!#tab ul li:first');
            }
            var currentTab = $.cookie('menu_cookie').split('!88!');
            var val1 = currentTab[0];
            var val2 = currentTab[1];
            alert(val1);
            alert(val2);
            //Hide all tabs
            $('#tab div').hide();
            //Show current tab, loaded from cookie
            $(val1).show();
            //Show hidden child div
            if (val1 === '#tab-1') {
                $('.fb-like-box').show();
            }
            var x = val2.substring(0, 1);
            //Chech if init Session        
            if (x === '#') {
                $(currentTab[1]).addClass('active');
            } else {
                var activate = JSON.parse(currentTab[1]);
                //Get json data for active
                alert("xxx");
                //alert(jsonp);
                **$(activate).parent().addClass('active');**
            }
            //On click function
            $('#tab ul li a').click(function() {
                $('#tab ul li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
                //Hide all tabs
                $('#tab div').hide();
                if (currentTab === "#tab-1") {
                    $('.fb-like-box').show();
                }
                $(currentTab).show();
                var sjson = JSON.stringify(this);
                var cooker = currentTab + '!88!' + sjson;
                alert(sjson);
                $.cookie('menu_cookie', cooker);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

So basically I want to pass the this object using a cookie, to then assign 
I want to do something like

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

by transporting the 'this' object through JSON.
The debug alerts have me guess that correct data is actually send, which leads me to believe that the problem lies in the line mentioned above

When using the non-transported object, the selected menu tab is highlighted nicely. 
The cookie is used to store this same object, to ensure the last selected tab is selected when the page is reloaded after clicking some link in a submenu.

The malfunctioning line would assign appropriate class to the last selected menu tab, but is not functioning.

thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?  What exactly is not working as you want it to?

Comment: Okay, I have specified the exact error in the question